# Angular 7 - Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BASE_URL]

Tags: angular, typescript

My component class is as follows:

```
  export class FetchDataComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

After having updated the project from Angular 5 to 7, I started getting the following console error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BASE_URL]

so I tried to solve the above error by defining the BASE_URL in environment.ts, then importing it to app.module.ts, and adding it to its providers array.

Now my new environment.ts looks as follows:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  BASE_URL: 'https://localhost:4430'
};
```

and my app.module.ts is as follows:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';


@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      FetchDataComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
      HttpClientModule,
      BASE_URL
    ])
  ],
  providers: [BASE_URL],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

But now the BASE_URL is not recognized and I get a compiling error:

> Cannot find name 'BASE_URL'

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Well, you’re not importing BASE_URL in your module. Try importing ‘enviroment’ and take the base url of that.

Comment: @MikeOne when I import 'environment' to the app.module and the I add 'environment.BASE_URL' to the providers array I get 'Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'https://localhost:4430' imported by the module 'AppModule''

Comment: Ueah that won’t work with the other stuff in your module. It’s just a string so you can’t use that as a provider or module import. To use it as a provider you’ll have to use a provider factory.

Comment: Yes, Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Provider'